# misprinted number in prime function

Tags: javascript

```js
function primeSieve() {
  for(i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
  let flag = true
    for(let j = 2; j < i/2; j++){
      if(i % j === 0){
        flag = false
      }
    }
    if(flag){
      console.log(i)
    }
  }
}

primeSieve();
```

Hi,

I'm studying some algos and ran into a prime sieve problem. I'm trying to print all prime numbers between 0 and 100 and it's working for the most part. However, i realized that 4 slipped in somehow and i can't figure out why for the life of me. Wondering if i can get a few pairs of eyes and see how 4 ended up being logged to the console and why that's the case.

thank you!

Comment: `j < i/2` ... so j is LESS THAN 2 ... perhaps `j<=i/2` will fix it

Comment: your code also outputs 0, and 1 - which are NOT prime

Answer (score 2):

Your condition in the inner loop:

```
for (let j = 2; j < i / 2; j++) {
```

is

```
j < i / 2
```

This means that when `i` is 4, once `j` gets to `2` (or, since `j` is always initialized to 2, before the first iteration), the loop breaks. So, without any iterations, there's never any chance for an `i` of `4` to get to `flag = false`.

Change to

```
for (let j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++) {
```

Also, per wikipedia:

> A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that cannot be formed by multiplying two smaller natural numbers.

So you should probably start `i` at 2, not 0.

Also, just like your `let j`, it would be good to declare `i` with `let` as well so as not to implicitly pollute the global scope:

```js
function primeSieve() {
  for (let i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
    let flag = true
    for (let j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++) {
      if (i % j === 0) {
        flag = false
      }
    }
    if (flag) {
      console.log(i)
    }
  }
}

primeSieve();
```

Comment: I would start `for i` loop at 2 - since that is the smallest prime :p

Comment: Omg, I was staring at it for like an hour trying to figure it out. This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!! I especially appreciate the tip about polluting the global scope as I hadn't considered it because of ecmascripts new standards when creating for loops

Answer (score 0):

Beside the including the value for `j` to check with `j <= i / 2`, you could omit  the use of a flag and use [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) with a label for the outer loop.

```js
function primeSieve() {
    outer: for (var i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
        for (var j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++) {
            if (i % j === 0) {
                continue outer;
            }
        }
        console.log(i);
    }
}

primeSieve();
```

Comment: That's a fine advice but doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović it does print the prime numbers (and only those).